# (Chrome Extensions) How to test onUpdateAvailable

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, event-handling

Is there a way to onUpdateAvailable manually (without using code)?
How can I trigger the onUpdateAvailable event without using code?
Because I also need to test my code in a "non-technical / non-developer" way.

Thanks.

Comment: What is 'a "non-technical / non-developer" way'?

Comment: Without using code.
Like, in a user's perspective.

Comment: How can I trigger the onUpdateAvailable event without using code?
I think this is a lot clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this listener to your extension:

```
chrome.runtime.onUpdateAvailable.addListener(function(){
    alert("update available!");
})
```

Have someone manually use your extension, and then you should issue an update while they are using it. This manual test just checks if the alert gets triggered. If you see the alert, or something visible from a "user's perspective", then the test passes.

The **only** way to manually/organically trigger `onUpdateAvailable` is actually having an update available and publishing that update (note the extension must be published as well).

Lastly, you should now manually request an update from the extensions page in Developer mode (Thanks @Xan for the tip)

---

Another way to request an update check is with a function bound to a button that a user can click.

Request an update check as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15842031/4926817) by clicking a button:

HTML

```
<button>Test onUpdateAvailable</button>
```

JavaScript

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', onUpdateAvailable);
});

// request an update
function test_onUpdateAvailable() {
    chrome.runtime.requestUpdateCheck(function(status) {
      if (status == "update_available") {
        console.log("update pending... expecting alert!");
      } else if (status == "no_update... not expecting alert!") {
        console.log("no update found");
      } else if (status == "throttled") {
        console.log("Oops, I'm asking too frequently - I need to back off.");
      }
    });
}
```

---

[Documentation for `onUpdateAvailable`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-requestUpdateCheck)

[Documentation for `requestUpdateCheck`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-requestUpdateCheck)

Comment: `onclick` in a Chrome extension? Aren't you [forgetting something](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#JSExecution)?

Comment: thanks for pointing that out, working on a fix. do you see any other issues with my answer?

Comment: I would stress that the *only* way to organically trigger it is to publish the extension, and then publish the update. As for requesting an update check, this doesn't need code - you can manually request one from the extensions page in Developer mode.

Comment: @xan Thanks again for the feedback, I'll work that in

Comment: Looks like there's no way around "publishing a new version". Thanks guys.

Comment: HI I have added this event but it did not fire. do I have to update the version? Can you help me with this?